# Only able to display first item of database

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I am trying to display items from my database. There are 6 items in it. However, it was only able to display the first item. But they are able to display all the 6 buttons. I have also attached a picture at the end to show how my page looks like currently. Is there any way to solve this problem? I want my item image, description and price to appear and followed by the button next. But as of now, its showing the first item and the 6 buttons.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
showlist();
});

function showlist(userid) {
var url = serverURL() + "/listitems.php"; 

categorynameID = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["categoryID"]);

var JSONObject = {
    "categoryID": decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["categoryID"])
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSONObject,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (arr) {
        _showitemResult(arr);
    },
    error: function () {
        validationMsg();
    }
});
}

function _showitemResult(arr) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $("#lblimagefile").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile); //display profile image
    $("#lblitemName").html(arr[i].itemName); //display item name
    $("#lblprice").html(arr[i].price); //display price 
    htmlstring = "<a href='#' class='ui-btn' id='btn" + arr[i].itemID + "'>View Item</a>"; //add a new [Category] button

    $("#result").append(htmlstring);

    $("#btn" + arr[i].itemID).bind("click", { id: arr[i].itemID }, function (event) {
        var data = event.data;
        showitem(data.id);
    });
}
}

function showitem(itemID) {
 //alert(categoryID);
 window.location = "showitem.html?itemID=" + itemID;
}
```

HTML

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="main-ui">
        <img id="lblimagefile" height="100">
        <div id="lblitemName"></div>
        <div id="lblprice"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: IDs must be unique per document.

Comment: If you change the HTML IDs to classes and the jQuery function to target those classes instead, it should work with no problem. Same with your buttons. If you’re going to add an event listener on them they will not work because they have the same HTML ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to htmlstring price, image and name template. htmlstring is your template for every post.

HTML:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="main-ui">
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
htmlstring = "<img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "' height='100'><div>" + arr[i].itemName + "</div><div>" + arr[i].price + "</div><a href='#' class='ui-btn' id='btn" + arr[i].itemID + "'>View Item</a>"; //add a new [Category] button

$("#result").append(htmlstring);
```

Comment: Hello! It is working now! Thank you for your help! :)